# Disabling sound of embedded flash object with html

Tags: html, flash, audio

Was wondering how to disable sound from an embedded flash object with html?

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the sound of a Flash movie in HTML I am afraid. What you can do is set up Javascript functions with the ExternalInterface object in Flash and you can call those  functions from Javascript.

ExternalInterface in the AS3 LangRef:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

If you don't have your Flash source files only the SWF I think you won't be able to do this.

Rob