# How to disable audio of the SWF file in Java Script (HTML)

Tags: html, flash, object-tag

I've tried the following code and it does not work . Was wondering how to disable sound from an embedded flash object with html.

Here is my code:

```
<object codebase="http://download.macromedia.vn/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="622" height="560" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> 
    <param name="movie" value="intro/flash/main.swf"> 
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="volume" value="0"> 
    <embed wmode="transparent" width="622" height="560" src="intro/flash/main.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.vn/go/getflashplayer" volume="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</object>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling sound of embedded flash object with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672471/disabling-sound-of-embedded-flash-object-with-html).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara , thanks for replay, I'm tried but code not work

Comment: Your HTML doesn't work because there is no attribute to disable the audio. You would need to code into the SWF an interface to disable it by JavaScript.