# How to get an embed division to not play audio on start

Tags: html, audio, embed

Hi I have the following code which runs my home page for my website, but whenever I start the site the audio from the embed division starts playing and ruins the effect of the website, so I was wondering if there was any attribute that i can put in the embed tag that would get it to not play the audio on start, or if there was any other way of fixing this problem that you would know of?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Web Portfolio: Patrick White's Index Page</title>
  <style>
     body {
     font-size: 1.1em;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-family: Century Gothic, Sans-serif;
     color: #02849D; /*dark navy blue*/
     text-align: left;
     /*Personal Addition*/
     background-image: url("Images/Black_Rainbow.jpg");
     background-size: 1900px 1400px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }
     h1 {
     font-size: 1.8em;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #02849D; 
     text-align: center;
     }
     a:link {
     color: #31AEC5;
     }
     a:visited {
     color: #015261;
     }
     a:hover {
     color: #505050;
     }
     #divembed {
     float: right
     }
     .button {
     background-color: #707070; /*grey*/
     border: none;
     color: #02849D; /*bright blue*/
     width: 450px;
     height: 75px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 75px; /*centers the text vertically*/
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 1.1em;
     font-family: Century Gothic;
     font-weight: bold;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
     <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Patrick White Web Portfolio</h1>
  <div id="divembed">
     <a href="http://www.gamesembedcode.com/2011/07/tennis-flash-game.html"></a>
     <embed src="http://www.freegaming.de/components/flash/7196382252.swf?affiliate_id=941efa0f97e566c4" quality="high" bgcolor="#e8ffff" width="480" height="480" menu="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
  </div>
  <div>
     <ul>
        <li>Patrick White</li>
        <li><a href="mailto:TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com">TotallyRealEmail@GOATS.com</a></li>
        <li>843-653-3474</li>
        <li>link to one of my favourite <a href="http://eelslap.com/" target="_blank">websites</a></li>
        <li>If you like goats, download my presentation! In either: <a href="Images/GOATS.pdf" download>PDF</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS_VIDEO.wmv" download>Video</a>, <a href="Images/GOATS.odp">Open Office</a> or <a href="Images/GOATS.ppt">Microsoft Powerpoint</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
     <ul>
        <li>I.T. 9 (1-2)</li>
        <li>Mr. Gabriel Jones</li>
        <li>Web Design</li>
        <li><a href ="http://go.vsb.bc.ca/schools/pointgrey/Pages/Default.aspx" target="_blank">Point Grey Secondary</a>, 2016-2017</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Accesibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
        <li><a href="Usability.html">Usability</a></li>
        <li><a href="Graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
        <li><a href="JavaScript.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="Tools.html">Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="Video.html">Video</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
  <main id="main">
     <p>This web portfolio includes examples of my works in Mr. Jones' Web Design class. It also includes my reflections (below) in what I learned with each unit of the course.</p>
     <h2>Unit 2</h2>
     <p>In this section, I learned the basics of a fundamental scripting language for website design; <i>HTML5</i>. I learned about some of the many tags that are useful in the design of websites that will assist me in my prospective career in web design. In this unit I was presented with many resources to ensure that my HTML code was formatted correctly and was error-free, in the form of online generators. We also learned a great deal about how to incorporate links and images into our file, of which I found particularly interesting. In this section we learned a lot about how to input the actual content of our websites, and I am very excited for the future units in which we get to further design this content to seem visually appealing.</p>
     <h2>Unit 3</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 4</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 5</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 6</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
     <h2>Unit 7</h2>
     <p>This section will be completed soon</p>
  </main>
  <a href="http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-me-and-the-key" target="blank" class="button">Click to Play One of My Favourite Games!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like this is possible unless you have access to the SWF source, at least according to this old answer with a broken link to adobe: [Disabling sound of embedded flash object with html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672471/disabling-sound-of-embedded-flash-object-with-html).  If it's your game, I'd highly recommend making your adjustments in there rather than in the page.  Changing the source (or asking the developer to) is the most highly recommended solution.

Most of what comes up is recommendations for users on browser extensions to mute audio from pages, which you could recommend if you don't have the source but are dedicated to including the game.  This article covers Chrome, Firefox, and Opera: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mute-sound-webpages-embedded-audio-flash/

This was probably the most in depth exchange I found on the subject: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26480933/Ho-to-disable-audio-of-the-SWF-file-in-Java-Script-HTML.html.  It's suggested that specifying a different player might allow you to change the "volume" parameter to "0" or "mute" parameter to "true" successfully.  I can't speak to the efficacy of the players they recommended for your purposes, but they're included with the last link.

The guy on that last one also included an "autoplay" parameter which was set to "false" in his example.  I figure that probably won't resolve your issue since he was having similar troubles even with that included, but trying it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response! Do you then know if there's a way remove all of the audio from an html document effectively resulting in this? Because I don't actually want any audio on the document at all

Comment: If there is a way in this specific case, I can't find it.  I'm relatively new to this stuff, so by all means keep looking.

Comment: As far as the html goes, different browsers can do different things with a few different audio formats: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp.  Acceptably formatted audio (or video) content have those tools easily available, but flash is different.

Afaik to change the how the flash game behaves (mute it's audio on startup, add a mute button/volume slider, etc.) you'd have to modify its source files directly, or have the game's dev do it.  If it helps, privy users often restrict flash in their browsers anyway, but presumably that's often to avoid exactly what you're trying to avoid.